# Able to login to docker private registry but can't push the image to it

Tags: docker, devops, artifactory

I have configured a docker private registry (Jfrog) through a container running on an Ubuntu machine.
I am able to login to private registry from **different host**, but as soon as I try to push an image after tagging it with repo name I am getting below error.

```
sudo docker pull alpine

sudo docker tag alpine docker.artifactory:8081/alpine:1.0

sudo docker push docker.artifactory:8081/alpine:1.0
The push refers to repository [docker.artifactory:8081/alpine]
77cae8ab23bf: Pushing [==================================================>]  5.553MB/5.553MB
http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

Here is docker login output

```
sudo docker login docker.artifactory:8081
Authenticating with existing credentials...different host
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/rahul/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

Since the registry is insecure I have already added below code in /etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
        "insecure-registries":["docker-local.artifactory:8081", "docker.artifactory:8081", "docker-remote.artifactory:8081"]
}
```

Note: If I pull an image from `docker-remote.artifactory:8081` and then tag it to `docker.artifactory:8081`, I can push the image without any issues

```
sudo docker pull docker-remote.artifactory:8081/alpine
sudo docker tag alpine docker.artifactory:8081/alpine:1.0
```

Here is docker version output

```
sudo docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.09.7
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.4
 Git commit:        2d0083d
 Built:             Fri Aug 16 14:19:38 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.7
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.4
  Git commit:       2d0083d
  Built:            Thu Aug 15 15:12:41 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

can someone help!

Comment: https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1874

Comment: @Adiii already followed this

Comment: `modifying "/etc/docker/daemon.json" didn't work for me.

Putting it under "/etc/sysconfig/docker" as below, worked.

INSECURE_REGISTRY="--insecure-registry 192.168.24.1:8787"`

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to resolve the issue after setting nginx as a reverse proxy in front of artifactory.
This configuration can be directly spin up with below command as mentioned in [here](https://bintray.com/jfrog/product/artifactory/download)

`curl https://jfrog.bintray.com/run/art-compose/latest/art-compose | sudo bash`